# Exclude filename from gluster replication

Tags: glusterfs

In glusterfs 3.5.2, is it possible to not replicate some file based on filename ?

I don't see this feature in filter or translator.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you have a replicate configuration, all files will get replicated.